# tcpdump is not capturing packets

Tags: tcpdump

Can anybody tell me what kind of error I have in this? It isn't reading any packets when I run it.

`nohup sudo tcpdump -i any host 10.0.1.107 and port 5060 and port 6060 -G 010 -W 015 -w capture_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.pcap -z gzip </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 &`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
and port 5060 and port 6060
```

If port is 5060, port cannot be 6060, and viceversa, so the condition you entered will always be false. You probable want to use `or` instead.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm new to this. So then should this work?    nohup sudo tcpdump -i any -n host 10.0.1.107 and (port 5060 or port 6060) -G 010 -W 015 -w capture_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.pcap -z gzip </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 &

Comment: You will probably find some issues using parenthesis barely on bash, you will probably want to wrap the expression in simple quotes: `tcpdump ... '... (port 5060  or port 6060) ...'`

Comment: No, `port 5060 and port 6060` *can* be true - but only for packets going to port 6060 from port 5060 or going to port 5060 from port 6060.

Answer (score 0):

`port 5060 and port 6060` is true only if one of the ports in the packet is 5060 and the other port is 6060, so it won't capture *all* packets to or from port 5060 or *all* packets to or from port 6060.

If you want all packets from or to port 5060 or from or to port 6060, you want `port 5060 or port 6060`, i.e. `host 10.0.1.107 and (port 5060 or port 6060)`, in quotes.